# Скачивание видео с Tik tok python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте кто знает подскажите нужно написать скрипт на питоне
его цели
скачивание постов с Инстаграм и с  тик ток
в интернете искал нашёл только не рабочий код

Comment: https://instaloader.github.io/

Comment: не удивительно что питонист пишет

Comment: @Lofectr даже интересно — почему?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Мне нужно чтоб скрипт спрашивал ссылку и по сылке загружал видео

Comment: @VictorVosMottor это нужно для тг бота

Comment: @Алекс `python tiktok-dl.py --output out.mp4 --verbose <VIDEO_URL_HERE>` <VIDEO_URL_HERE> — ссылкa

Comment: @VictorVosMottor 
_Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tiktok-dl.py", line 89, in <module>
    mainline()
  File "tiktok-dl.py", line 68, in mainline
    r1 = download_data(args.uri)
  File "tiktok-dl.py", line 24, in download_data
    http = urllib3.PoolManager(10, headers=user_agent)
NameError: name 'urllib3' is not defined
"sender_web_id" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
"is_from_webapp" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом._
Ошибка

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor 3

Comment: не знаю........

Answer (score 5):

## Instloader

```
pip3 install instaloader
```

[docs](https://instaloader.github.io/)

## Tiktol-dl

[link](https://github.com/tonetheman/tiktok-dl)

```
python tiktok-dl.py --output out.mp4 --verbose VIDEO_URL_HERE
```